# How to save data of Recycler View under Fragment to save bandwith consumption ?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I am a beginner in android

I have an Activity A (MainActivity) with two Fragments (F1,F2). Where the Fragment F1 having o RecyclerView(GridView) and Fragment F2 having RecyclerView(ListView).

To Feed data to these RecyclerView i am using Volley.

On starting application 
data loads in respective RecyclerView successfully **BUT when I navigate to Activity A to B and return back to Activity A using back stack in Action bar data of RecyclerView gets parsed again through network** so how to save the data of RecyclerView Once Created throughout the App life cycle to save Bandwidth consumption .

Is data is not properly geting Cache?

Is fragment Reload the view on Backstack?

Comment: When you press back fragment is recreated yes. You can use `SharedPreferences` to store data in activity A and avoid making network calls  each time.  You can access the `sharedpref` data from any activity. Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example